# How to add path to source code in python (pycharm) project

Tags: python

I have inherited a project that has code in a package that has imports that are assuming code in that package are in the root directory.

For example, given this directory structure

```
my_project
  mod_1
  mod_2
  - folder1
    mod_3
    mod_4
    - folder2
      mod_5

mod_5 would have an import like:
  import mod_3
  import mod_4
```

When I try to run this code I get the error that mod_1 cannot be found.

If I change the imports to this everything seems to work

```
  import folder1.mod_3
  import folder1.mod_4
```

However, this is not a viable solution as this is part of a long running opensource project and clearly this is not the intent of the original authors and clearly something that has been working for others without the above modifications.

How do I craft a virtual environment that will essentially add folder_1 directly to the path such that modules in folder_1 can be referenced as being in the root folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pycharm, use this flow

Select the `source dir` -> `Right-Click` -> Choose `Mark Directory As` -> Choose `Sources Root`

It will make the directory as a root and solve the import issues.

Comment: Thanks :) I've been banging my head on other issues... getting Docker code to debug in PyCharm has been an adventure.

Comment: If you use the professional version, you get support quickly .